# I want to download new update of Blender but I don't want to lose my projects. What is the procedure?

Tags: light

Title says it all. I want to download new update of Blender but I don't want to lose my projects.

Comment: The project isn't influenced by the reinstallation or deletion of blender, just install new blender delete the old and open the blender file in new version. Which version are you using?

Comment: I'm using 2.8..

Comment: Then no problem, just install 2.82 there is an installation now. You can delete the folder for 2.8. Of course if you have your blender files in other file. When you open your project it will open in 2.82

Comment: There's no need to delete/uninstall the old version of Blender, you can keep multiple versions at the same time.

Comment: Just to add - when you install a new version on Windows, it'll keep opening .blend files with 2.8. You have to manually change the default app :).